# Join Two Array based on Index and Index Value using Linq Query Expression Syntax

Tags: c#, linq

I want to join two arrays with one array containing index value and a second array containing index position.

```
string[] numStrings = new[] { "Zero", "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine"};
int[] nums = new[] { 2, 32, 70 };
```

The output I want:

```
2   Two
32  Three-Two
70  Seven-Zero
```

I tried below query

```
var strValuList = (from d in nums
                            from p in numStrings.Select((value, index) => new { value = value, index = index })
                            where p.index == d
                            select new { num = d, p.value}).ToList();
```

but it returns only

2  Two

Comment: So.... what did you try? Looks like an assignment. Just try yourself, else you won't learn anything. We can make up the most beautiful linq queries/string joins that solves this. But are you able to read/understand them?

Comment: List<string> strValuList = (from d in nums
                               from p in numStrings.Select((value, index) => new { value = value, index = index })
                               where p.index == d
                               select p.value).ToList();

Comment: You might update your question instead of commenting ;-)

Comment: I'd suggest playing with `%` and `/` to divide by 10 and handle one digit at a time.

Comment: Doing this in one query is more complicated than necessary. Hint: `do { yield return numStrings[n % 10]; n /= 10; } while (n != 0)`. (`.ToString` and going over each character is another approach, though it might be considered "cheating": `nums.Select(n => ("" + n).Select(c => numStrings[c - '0']))`.)

Comment: I can easily write some c# function to do this but I thought there might be an easy way of doing it using some Linq "let, into or join" operator :)

Comment: @Hemendr It depends what you understand under _"Easy way"_.

Comment: The loop you'd do to extract the digits from a number can certainly be written in a LINQ query, and you can join that up with the digit array. It's just not particularly sane to do it this way.

Comment: `from c in "70" join s in (numStrings.Select((n, i) => new { n, i })) on c - '0' equals s.i select s.n`. There you go, I shoehorned in a `join`. But, of course, nobody would do this rather than just indexing the array!

Comment: Note that LINQ does have `let`, and you *can* assign the results of a query to a bound value, if you're so inclined: `from n in nums let d = from c in n.ToString() select numStrings[c - '0'] select new { num = n, value = String.Join("-", d) }`. Most people would consider this less natural than chaining `Select`s.

Answer (score 1):

Try it yourself first, then you can look at answer:

Hint:

```
IEnumerable<int> SplitNum(int num)
{
    while (num  > 0)
    {
        yield return num % 10;
        num /= 10;
    }
}
```

Answer:

```
string[] numStrings = new[] { "Zero", "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine" };
int[] nums = new[] { 2, 32, 70 };
```

(Hover mouse on yellow part for the answer [I will remove spoiler part after some time])

> string[] result = nums.Select(n => string.Join("-", SplitNum(n).Reverse().Select(i => numStrings[i]))).ToArray();
>
>
>  **[DotNetFiddle example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Q4kcfl)**

Comment: It's nice but complicated to understand. I upvote it as I've learned from your answer.

Comment: @DmitryS Well you can always use `string/ToString()`s, `char`s and `int.Parse` to get desired result, but I felt unnatural (maybe it will feel less unnatural if you use `$"{num}"` instead of `num.ToString()`, but anyway too much `string->char->string->int` conversion) to do that much actions for a simple math task - to get separate digits from number. For the linq part, it is not too complicated, OP just need to read carefully and understand each part of that expression.

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] numStrings = new[] { "Zero", "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine"};
int[] nums = new[] { 2, 32, 70 };

var dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();

foreach(var n in nums)
{
    var str = string.Join("-", n.ToString().Select(s => numStrings[Convert.ToInt32(s.ToString())]));
    dict[n] = str;
}
```

Comment: Why you need `if (n < 10)` part?

Answer (score 0):

I solve it without much complexity. Thanks, @Jeroen Mostert for your advice

```
string[] numStrings = new[] { "Zero", "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine" };
int[] nums = new[] { 2, 32, 70 };
(from d in nums
select new
{
    num = d,
    parts = d.ToString().Select(o=> Convert.ToInt32(o.ToString())),
    parts2 = d.ToString().Select(o => numStrings[Convert.ToInt32(o.ToString())]),
    parts3 = string.Join("-",d.ToString().Select(o => numStrings[Convert.ToInt32(o.ToString())]).ToArray())
}).Dump();
```

Output in LinqPad:
[image]

Comment: You do realize `dict` is semantically equal to `numStrings`, right? `dict[x] == numStrings[x]` for all `x` between `0` and `9`, inclusive.

Comment: But given what you really want to be looking up is the `char`s from the string then perhaps a dictionary with keytype `char` would have been better and saved a bunch of converting chars to ints...

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the many ways to do it:

```
void Main()
{
    string[] numStrings = new[] { "Zero", "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine" };
    int[] nums = new[] { 2, 32, 70 };

    Func<int, string> numToWord = (x) => {
        List<string> words = new List<string>();
        do {
            words.Add( numStrings[x%10] );
            x /= 10;
        } while (x > 0);
        var w = words.Reverse<string>();
        return string.Join("-",w);
    }; 

    var result = nums.Select(n => numToWord(n));

    foreach (var element in result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(element);
    }
}
```